# AngularJS and parsing body text

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a website with AngularJS, driven by user-generated content, which can use custom tags such as `[js-code]...[/js-code]` to display the text inside those sections differently.

The API sends me a single string of body text which contains the tags, to be parsed on the client.

If I were using native JavaScript or JQuery, I suppose that I would iterate through each character, adding to a DOM element, and when I encountered one of these tags, I would create a new DOM element with formatting determined by the tag.

However, in AngularJS, we are discouraged from performing DOM manipulations in JavaScript code.

I cannot conceive of a way to accomplish my goal, using just AngularJS directives.

An additional complication is that the text needs to be editable, with real-time preview. This would seem to preclude slicing the string into an array of sections. (Maybe it doesn't; it just seems like it would be too slow.)

Is it possible to do what I am attempting within the AngularJS framework? If so, how?

Comment: I think it's important to make a distinction here.  There is a misconception about manipulating the DOM that isn't really clear.  Yes, you are discouraged from manipulating the DOM, in cases where two way binding can serve the same purpose.  But inside a directive, with data that purposely isn't two way bound, using JS to build the HTML snippet that the directive will output is a valid approach.  What isn't a good idea is writing a directive that finds elements outside itself in the DOM tree and manipulates those without angular's knowledge.

Comment: Yes, there is nothing wrong with manipulating the DOM. AngularJS provides you hooks where doing so is recommended and appropriate. i.e. Link function or watch handlers in link function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Plnkr Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/uGGM8iWLgOfyAH4DB9Cm?p=preview)

You can leverage Angular's templating engine to build your own live template editor complete with custom code tags.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<h3>Text Editor</h3>
<textarea ng-model="model"></textarea>

<h3>Raw Preview</h3>
<div>
  {{ model }}
</div>
<h3>Live Preview</h3>
<js-code-content model="model">
   Loading...
</js-code-content>
```

**Custom Directive**

```
  app.directive('jsCodeContent', function($compile) {
     return {
       restrict: 'E',
       scope: {
         model: '=model'
       },
       link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            scope.$watch('model', function(value, oldValue) {

                var model = value || '';
                // encode HTML
                model = angular.element('<div></div>').text(model).html();
                model = model.replace(/\[js:bold\]/g, '<js-bold>');
                model = model.replace(/\[\/js:bold\]/g, '</js-bold>');
                model = model.replace(/\[js:italic\]/g, '<js-italic>');
                model = model.replace(/\[\/js:italic\]/g, '</js-italic>');
                model = model.replace(/\[js:code\]/g, '<js-code>');
                model = model.replace(/\[\/js:code\]/g, '</js-code>');
                model = model.replace(/\[js:hilight\]/g, '<js-hilight>');
                model = model.replace(/\[\/js:hilight\]/g, '</js-hilight>');


                  var e = angular.element('<content></content>');
                  e.html(model);
                  element.empty();
                  element.append(e);
                  $compile(e)(scope);


            });

       }
     }
  });
```

**JS Code Templates**

```
  app.directive('jsCode', function() {
     return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<code ng-transclude></code>'
     }
  })
  app.directive('jsBold', function() {
     return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<b ng-transclude></b>'
     }
  })      
  app.directive('jsItalic', function() {
     return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<i ng-transclude></i>'
     }
  })      
  app.directive('jsHilight', function() {
     return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<span class="highlight" ng-transclude></span>'
     }
  })
```

Comment: Wow, that is a very thorough answer. Thanks

Comment: I have one additional question. What if I need to use a second directive that wants me to pass the text between the tag as an attribute? The directive wants `<code-mirror model='model'></code-mirror>` where `model` is a $scope variable containing the text between the `[js:code][/js:code]` tags.