# AngularJS $compile and external directive ui-codemirror

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-compile, ui-codemirror

I am trying to use the external module, `angular-ui-codemirror`, to display the `$element.html()` of an enclosing AngularJS directive in a code-formatted block, using nested directive `ui-codemirror`.

If you want to know why I need to do this, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34700128/angularjs-and-parsing-body-text).

I can easily see from examples how to get this going with static text. And I can pass the `innerHTML` of the enclosing directive alright. It just doesn't compile afterward into a `ui-codemirror` directive.

I see, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837870/in-a-custom-angular-directive-pass-the-innerhtml-as-an-attribute-to-another-dir), that it is probably necessary to use the `$compile` service to do this, but I cannot adapt that example to this situation.

Here is some example AngularJS code:

```
angular.module('articles', ['ui.codemirror']).directive('jsCode', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function($scope, $element) {    
      $scope.codeText = $element.html();
      var template = '<div ' +
          'ui-codemirror="{ ' +
            'lineNumbers: true, ' +
            'theme:\'twilight\', ' +
            'readOnly: \'nocursor\', ' +
            'lineWrapping: true, ' +
            'mode: \'xml\'}" ' +
          'ng-bind="codeText"></div>';
      var linkFn = $compile(template);
      var content = linkFn($scope);
      $element.replaceWith(content)
    }
  };
});
```

and the html:

```
<js-code>
&lt;html style=&quot;color: green&quot;&gt;
&lt;!-- this is a comment --&gt;
&lt;head&gt;
&lt;title&gt;HTML Example&lt;/title&gt;
&lt;/head&gt;
&lt;body&gt;
The indentation tries to be &lt;em&gt;somewhat &amp;quot;do what
I mean&amp;quot;&lt;/em&gt;... but might not match your style.
&lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;
</js-code>
```

I created [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YELL3GzO775hmctNcX7G?p=preview) to illustrate my dilemma. The first block is unformatted. The second block (static) is formatted.

Comment: Do you need/want to bind the html using the `codeText` variable? In other words, will the content of that variable change outside of the element? If not you can just use `$element.html()` when you build the template string - but I think that something within the codemirror lib relies on the element being already in the dom so it doesn't work totally right, even after you click inside of it.  See this http://plnkr.co/edit/2d3Y8Ic9XFbsloBgT7wv?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

replace in jsCode directive

```
'ng-bind="codeText"></div>';
```

by

```
'ng-model="codeText"></div>';
```

and use

```
$element.text()
```

instead of

```
$element.html()
```